# Twitter Bootstrap - How to get buttons to be block level only on extra small and small devices

Tags: css, twitter-bootstrap

I have the following HTML:

```
<a href="javascript:void(0)" class="btn btn-primary btn-block">Start</a>
```

This works fine, however, I don't want the button to stretch across the screen on medium and large devices (essentially desktops). Is there a way to achieve this out of the box with Bootstrap?

Answer (score 5):

Responsive CSS.

You can define the max width or/and height of any section of CSS with `@media` tags, like in the bootstrap-responsive.css. Here is an example.

```
@media (min-width: 400px) and (max-width: 600px) {
    /* Code here */
}
```

That code will be applied to all devices with a minimum browser window width of 400 pixels, and a maximum of 600 pixels.

You can grab the code for `btn`, `btn-primary` and `btn-block` from bootstrap.css or bootstrap-responsive.css (Some responsive examples in there), and put it in a `<style></style>` tag or in a separate CSS file, and edit it accordingly with responsive CSS.

Answer (score 0):

I achieved a similar behavior while avoiding code duplication by using the `.btn-block` class as a mixin.
Here is the corresponding `less` code:

```
@import (reference) "node_modules/bootstrap/less/mixins.less";
@import (reference) "node_modules/bootstrap/less/variables.less";
@import (reference) "node_modules/bootstrap/less/buttons.less";

@media only screen and (max-width: @screen-xs-min) {
  .btn-block-xs {
    .btn-block;
  }
}
```

The `btn-block-xs` class will behave like `btn-block` but *only* for screen of `width <= @screen-xs-min`.